# How to Track Facebook Social Plugin (Like/Recommend) using FB.Event.Subscribe (edge.create)

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm using the Facebook Social Plugin for the Like/Recommend button. I'm testing it on the following page:

http://christopherbush.co.uk/igk/share-test.php

The button is programmed to like a specific page (ivegotkids.com) and that works perfectly. I've added the Meta Tags so the correct information is posted on Facebook when a person clicks on the button. All I need to do now is add tracking so the name of the person who has clicked it can be stored in my database.

Facebook says that you can do this using the Event.Subscribe function but their only example tells you how to display an alert... I don't want to display an alert. I want to grab the person's name and deposit it into my database so I can check who has liked the page and who hasn't.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php // Adds the Facebook Javascript SDK ?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>




<?php // Adds the Facebook "Like" Button ?>
<fb:like href="http://ivegotkids.com" send="false" width="450" show_faces="true" action="recommend" font="trebuchet ms"></fb:like>




<?php // Adds the Facebook Tracking Code ?>


<script>
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',

    function(response) {


        alert('You Recommended: ' + response);


    }
);
</script>
```

I need to change the "alert" line to whatever it is I'm missing... This is where I should be putting my tracking code but I just cannot find any examples of what I can put there to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will **not** share the user's data with you unless you create an app and the user explicitly authorize it.

If you read the `edge.create` event [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/):

> `edge.create` - fired when the user likes something (fb:like). The
>   response parameter to the callback function contains the URL that was
>   liked:

```
"http://www.example.com/article1.php"
```

As you can see, the URL link is the only response you will get. So unless you are using [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) this is **not** possible.

Comment: Hi there ifaour, I do have an App already. I'd like to be able to use it to achieve this. It is extremely necessary. Any change you can give me some pointers on how I go about this?

Comment: If you already have the user Facebook connected to your site, then just use ajax to store the user data along with the link. Something like my answer [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5220877/tracking-facebook-like-referrals/5221538#5221538).

Comment: Hi again and thanks for continuing to help. I already have an app registered on facebook but I'm not using it to allow people to login to my site. I already have a login system for my site that logs registered users into 4 different systems at once so facebook connect would not be compatible with that. What I need to do is this: 1) User visits site, 2) User shares on FB, 3) Name is collected and entered into prize draw.   Any chance on getting a step by step on how to achieve this using the app i have registered and the like/recommend button? or a pre-filled wall post?

Comment: Just follow the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) once the user is logged-in with his Facebook, use [FB.login()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) (check the example) to get the name and then use the [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to subscribe to `edge.create`